# While loop ends although condition is not fully achieved

Tags: r, loops

I am using the below code to find how many iterations it takes for the confidence interval to become approximately 25. However, when I run it it stops with interval lengths which do not fit the criteria. They are close, but not between 24.99 and 25.01.

```
counter <- 0
r <- 50
while((r-25)>0.01){
    counter <- counter + 1
    a <- replicate(500,profit())
    CI_l <- mean(a) - (sd(a)/sqrt(500))*qnorm(0.975)
    CI_u <- mean(a) + (sd(a)/sqrt(500))*qnorm(0.975)
    r <- CI_u-CI_l
}
cat("It took ", counter, " tries to get to an interval of", r)
```

I am sure that there are also easier ways to do this but my main concern is whether R is doing something wrong or I am.

Comment: Please edit your question to ensure reproducibility. `Error in profit() : could not find function "profit"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `r` is well below 25, then `(r-25)` is well below `0.01`, therefore the `while` condition is false and it ends.

```r
r <- 1
(r-25)
# [1] -24
(r-25) > 0.01
# [1] FALSE
```

Use `abs(.)`,

```r
abs(r-25) > 0.01
# [1] TRUE
```

leading to

```r
while(abs(r-25) > 0.01){
  # ...
}
```

I applaud the use of tolerance in a test of inequality; often the first attempt is `while (r != 25)`, but according to [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272) and [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) it may never occur (even if `r` is very close to 25).